# JavaScript: Получение данных без перезагрузки страницы с изменением URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, существует ли какой-нибудь плагин javascript для упрощения получения и обработки данных без перезагрузки страницы с изменение url адреса?

Например, на сайте есть фильтр и список объявлений. При нажатии на параметр происходит фильтрация объявлений без перезагрузки страницы и вместо прежних объявлений, появляются новые. URL при этом меняется.

Например, сайт триваго, там, если выставить класс отеля или рейтинг, то автоматически подгрузятся новые объявления. https://www.trivago.ru/?aHotelTestClassifier=&iIncludeAll=0&aPartner=&aDateRange%5Barr%5D=2018-07-17&aDateRange%5Bdep%5D=2018-07-26&aPriceRange%5Bfrom%5D=0&aPriceRange%5Bto%5D=0&iPathId=86737&aGeoCode%5Blat%5D=55.751125&aGeoCode%5Blng%5D=37.62368&iGeoDistanceItem=0&aCategoryRange=0%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5&aOverallLiking=4%2C5&sOrderBy=relevance%20desc&bTopDealsOnly=false&iRoomType=1&cpt=8673703%2C152700&iViewType=0&bIsSeoPage=false&bIsSitemap=false&

Как это работает?

Путь решения я вижу пока что в ручную: 
1) Выбрать в фильтре все значения, которые checked, строить на основе этих данных новый URL
2) Отправлять на сервер данные и разбирать полученную JSON строку

Но хотелось бы узнать, может быть есть какие-то плагины, шаблонизаторы, как проще это сделать?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам хочется в обычный классический сайт добавить функцию переходов по страницам "без перезагрузки" страницы — [Turbolinks.js](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) вам в помощь. Его просто нужно подключить на страницу и будет магия по подмене head и body тегов с переписыванием url и работой истории в браузере.

В то же время то, что вы описали и привели в пример — не совсем то же самое, что turbolinks. Там работа за счёт javascript кода по общению с сервером и обновлению данных об отелях по параметрам пользователей. Для удобства пользователей и чтобы можно было поделиться результатами выбора с другим пользователем, добавлен функционал по обновлению URL строки и записи состояния в history api (чтобы кнопка назад в браузере работала) при изменении параметров фильтра. Конкретные шаблонизаторы не подскажу, реализовать подобное можно самому довольно быстро как на чистом JS, так и с jQuery, AngularJS, VueJS и т.п. — примеров по AJAX запросам форм и обновлению содержимого страницы масса, к ним лишь нужно подключить работу с history api для записи состояний изменения формы в историю.